# Using AWS Simple Directory for on-premise clients

Tags: amazon-web-services, active-directory, ldap

Our company is growing and we need to deploy some sort of directory service. Most of our platform is already running on AWS, so I have been looking into using AWS Simple Directory as our AD, which seems to be working fine for EC2 instances.

However, I can't find any documentation explaining how to let on-premise client computers join the Simple Directory.

Is that even possible?

Comment: What platform are your OSes running on?

Comment: @T-Heron It's a mix if both Mac and Windows 10 machines.